# Pagination inside of tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, pagination, kaminari

I have 2 tabs with bootstrap for user messages - inbox and outbox, and using kaminari

```
<div id="allmessages" >

    <div class="tabbable"> 
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#inbox" data-toggle="tab">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="#outbox" data-toggle="tab">outbox</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="inbox">
            <%= render @incoming_msgs %>
            <%= paginate @incoming_msgs %>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="outbox">
            <%= render @outgoing_msgs%>
            <%= paginate @outgoing_msgs%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is, that when going on page 2 in the inbox and then clicking on the outbox tab I get to page 2 of the outbox..

```
http://localhost:3000/users/messages?page=2#outbox
```

is it possible to reverse the order or have a pagination per tab?

Answer (score 2):

Passing the param_name option to the paginate method will allow you to page through each object array independently. Right now they are both using the default param name 'page'.

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="inbox">
    <%= render @incoming_msgs %>
    <%= paginate @incoming_msgs, param_name: :incoming_msgs_page %>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="outbox">
    <%= render @outgoing_msgs%>
    <%= paginate @outgoing_msgs, param_name: :outgoing_msgs_page %>
</div>
```

Make sure to reference the new param names in the controller

```
@incoming_msgs = mailbox.inbox.page(params[:incoming_msgs_page]).per(25)
@outgoing_msgs = mailbox.outbox.page(params[:outgoing_msgs_page]).per(25)
```

Answer (score 0):

short answer - use ajax pagination

http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax